# Hide github variable value being automatically echoed in logs during assignment

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-reusable-workflows

I am having a reusable workflow running two separate reusable workflows: a `get-variable`, which `outputs` a long string variable and a `use-variable`. My `use-variable` workflow is simply looking like this at the moment:

```
use-variable:
needs: get-variable
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
name: Reuse variable
steps:
   - uses: actions/checkout@v4
   - name: Run Integration Tests
     run: |
      TMP_VAR=${{ needs.get-variable.outputs.MY_VARIABLE }}
```

The `TMP_VAR=${{ needs.get-variable.outputs.MY_VARIABLE }}` prints automatically in the logs the content of `MY_VARIABLE` which is not what I want in my case and I cannot find a way to prevent this. I have tried to use `::add-mask::${{ needs.get-auth-token.outputs.API_TOKEN }}` to mask it and yet the content is shown during the assignment even though I am not echoing anything. Is there a way to prevent this from happening by keeping the two workflows as they are right now, hence `get-variable` being a workflow which `outputs` the variable and `use-variable` a separate workflow that reuses that output?

Comment: Have you looked at e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#masking-a-value-in-a-log?

Comment: @jonrsharpe what part exactly? I have looked at that docs, where also the `::add-mask::` part is explained, which I have tried as I mentioned above and yet nothing. The problem I am having seems to be an explicit logging whenever the variable is referenced. Am I missing something else?

Comment: You could eventually consider this output as a secret following [this section](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-masking-and-passing-a-secret-between-jobs-or-workflows).

Comment: @GuiFalourd true, I have read also that section. But in that case I would need to setup a key vault (Azure key vault? AWS secret manager? or...?) and all the user access that comes with setting such a thing. And just for 1 "secret" is a bit of an overkill. But to go back to what I am experiencing, is it normal that just by referencing a ${{ }} Github variable it gets outputted in the logs? Because as you can see I am not explicitely echoing it anywhere.

Comment: It's because outputs are shared between jobs, and exposed by GitHub on the UI in that case. An alternative "less overkill" than the other one could be to use an action to set the output value as Github repo secret instead on the first job, and access the value as secret in the second job (you won't need to use outputs in that case anymore, just a dependency between jobs).